# Page gets refreshed without displaying Alert in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried displaying success message post followed by a refresh on a button ng-click. The page get refreshed but the message is not shown. I debugged the code and the console output surprised me.

**JS CODE**

```
 $scope.Save = function (data) {

    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');

    //var promise = $http.get($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus');

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;
    console.log("1");

    $scope.showstatus = true;
    console.log("2");

    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    console.log("3");

    $(".publishStatus").show();
    console.log("4");

    $timeout($scope.Refresh1(), 2000);
    console.log("5");

 }
 $scope.Refresh1 = function () {

    //refresh
    console.log("6");
    $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });

 }
```

**Console Output**

[image]

My doubt is when it is executing in order 1,2,3,4 then why the alert is not shown on the page and getting refreshed? How can I achieve the stability?

Comment: how do you display your alert after filing it with your data ?

Comment: You seem to be re-posting your code/question for the fourth time. Plus it seems that you forgot to add the corresponding html in your question as the only thing that happens without any doubt, is setting some $scope.properties with some values. There is no way to get a full grasp of what is going on like this. Besides that, you're forcefully making the user of your application wait 2 seconds before he can see the update. Seems like a bad idea/structure.

Answer (score -1):

```
{ type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.',show:true }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the quesiton.